# What is the definition of rotation matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix), it seems that rotation matrixes are orthogonal matrices with determinant 1. But is it definition of rotation matrix? I mean, are all orthogonal matrixes with determinant 1 rotation matrixes?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68100/what-are-the-requirements-for-a-rotation-matrix?rq=1